# How to install USB Sounds Adapter?

Tags: usb, audio

I've bought a CONCEPTRONIC USB SOUND ADAPTER that I want to connect to my stereo. I plugged this USB adapter into the Raspberry Pi.

`aplay -l` showing the following output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
Subdevices: 8/8
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: Set [C-Media USB Headphone Set], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I don't know if the USB is recognized and correctly working but I think it isn't because there is no sound.

How can I install the driver/firmware so it plays my music?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the `Set [C-Media USB Headphone Set], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]` is your USB sound card.

Test if the card is running by typing `alsamixer`, press `F6` to select which sound card to use and press enter on the USB audio. Then try and play some music with `mpg123` or similar.

To change the default device to your new one, edit `/etc/asound.conf` to look like:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
    device 0
}
```